# CAML query seems to be ignored

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, jsom, caml

My CAML query seems to be ignored as I'm getting the same result no matter which dates I send.

I found an JavaScript example which seemed to work fine until I started to edit my query

```
function getListItems(webUrl, listTitle, viewXml) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
    var queryPayload = {
        'query': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
            'ViewXml': viewXml
        }
    };
    return executeJson(url, "POST", null, queryPayload);
}

function executeJson(url, method, headers, payload) {
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if (method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }
    var ajaxOptions =
    {
        url: url,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
        ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

And this is the CAML I'm sending

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Location"/>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
        <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
    </OrderBy>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">2017-01-31T22:59:59.999Z</Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
    </Where>
    <QueryOptions>
        <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
    </QueryOptions>
</View>
```

No matter which dates I enter I'm always getting the same five events between 2016-11-22 and 2016-11-25.

Thew 'ViewFields' seem to be ignored as well. Is this some kind of "dumb user isn't able to query correctly" fallback?

The SharePoint-Version I'm using is SharePoint Foundation 2013

Thanks!

Comment: I find that SP returns unexpected results when it gets confused with the CAML.  Have you tried including a [IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'](http://spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/camlquery-to-include-timestamp.aspx) attribute on your Value node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's most probably a syntax error in your CAML query. What was the original CAML you used (the one that worked fine)?
I think you're missing a parent `<Query>` tag arround `Where` and `OrderBy`. your query should look like:

```
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Location"/>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
        <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
        </OrderBy>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Geq>
                    <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                    <Value Type="DateTime">2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z</Value>
                </Geq>
                <Lt>
                    <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                    <Value Type="DateTime">2017-01-31T22:59:59.999Z</Value>
                </Lt>
            </And>
        </Where>
    <Query>
    <QueryOptions>
        <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
    </QueryOptions>
</View>
```

(reference for the `View` element: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438338.aspx; as you can see, `View` does not have `Where` as a possible child element, only `Query`).

Comment: Oh thank you! I've copied so many different sources that I've lost track of the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

As Evariste said, you should add the Query node. I'd also add the IncludeTimeValue property in order to avoid time issues.

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Location"/>
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
    </OrderBy>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <Geq>
          <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
          <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Lt>
          <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
          <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2017-01-31T22:59:59.999Z</Value>
        </Lt>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <QueryOptions>
    <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
  </QueryOptions>
</View>
```

On the other hand, to avoid the usage of CAML queries, you can use rest services like this:

```
var select = "$select=Title,EventDate,EndDate";
var filter = "$filter= (EventDate ge datetime'2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z') and (EventDate lt datetime'2017-01-31T22:59:59.999Z')";
var orderBy = "$orderby=EventDate asc";


var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?" + select + "&" + filter  + "&" + orderBy;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
            // do something with ata.d.results
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error: " + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what "Time issues" could be?

Comment: I have to stop pressing enter to add a new Line ...
Thank you for the second part of your post! I'm not a big fan of CAML to be honest ...

Comment: A Time Issue could be: if _EventDate_ is **31/01/2017** and the _IncludeTimeValue_ property is not present, then the query will not include items with _EventDate_ = **31/01/2017**. If we use that property the query will return items with _EventDate_ < **31/01/2016 22:59:59**.

Comment: Thank you!

After testing the filter you posted I remember why I switched to CAML...
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}